# "form element select" moveable not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, moveable

I use moveable js.

https://github.com/daybrush/moveable

I need to make "form element select" moveable but not working. I record a video for this problem. I hope help me fix this problem.

codepen -> `https://codepen.io/daybrush/pen/VoQypZ`

I show in video my problem

this is video -> `https://streamable.com/0bibdv`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I explain everything in the video and I paste codepen URL